# Air-conditioner or air-conditioned

Tags: word-choice

Which is written correctly:

> I caught a cold because of an air-conditioner
>    or
>   I caught a cold
>   because I was flying in an air-conditioned plane

Comment: Both are correct, the second just has more detail. Please can you add the reasons why you think one or the other would not be correct?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, both are written correctly, though you have a typo there: "am" should be "an".